# Why does /dev/disk/by-id directory have cdrom device only and which one of /dev/disk/by-X is recommended for creating zfs pools?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, zfs, zfsonlinux, udev

Im running a ubuntu 16.04 machine in esxi enviroment, i am going through zfs on linux [faq](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/wiki/faq#selecting-dev-names-when-creating-a-pool) and it recommends to use /dev/disk/by-id for home servers due to inconsistent nature of /dev/sdX names but when i list files on /dev/disk the by-id only have cdrom device symlink on it.

```
root@sandbox1:/usr/lib# ls -l /dev/disk/*
/dev/disk/by-id:
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Mar 23 14:01 ata-VMware_Virtual_IDE_CDROM_Drive_10000000000000000001 -> ../../sr0

/dev/disk/by-label:
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Mar 23 14:01 ISOIMAGE -> ../../sr0

/dev/disk/by-partuuid:
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar 23 14:01 0ab37a34-0257-4619-b03e-d0d517ae81b0 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar 23 14:01 117b8f72-31ce-453c-96ad-1c3a6a7254ca -> ../../sda4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar 23 14:01 13901c1b-5f31-4ec8-82d4-a6f90867cb0c -> ../../sda9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar 23 14:01 321d414b-3d47-4545-acc5-36e5ecf8d3b8 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar 23 14:01 6d13446d-9d6f-4ca3-825e-c505f244e73c -> ../../sda5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar 23 14:01 94e037c9-ee9e-40b2-b634-2382734e7fdc -> ../../sda3

/dev/disk/by-path:
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Mar 23 14:01 pci-0000:00:07.1-ata-2 -> ../../sr0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Mar 23 14:01 pci-0000:00:10.0-scsi-0:0:0:0 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar 23 14:01 pci-0000:00:10.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar 23 14:01 pci-0000:00:10.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar 23 14:01 pci-0000:00:10.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part3 -> ../../sda3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar 23 14:01 pci-0000:00:10.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part4 -> ../../sda4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar 23 14:01 pci-0000:00:10.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part5 -> ../../sda5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar 23 14:01 pci-0000:00:10.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part9 -> ../../sda9

/dev/disk/by-uuid:
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Mar 23 14:01 2017-06-18-10-12-11-00 -> ../../sr0
```

which method(by-id,by-path etc) is recommended approach on virtualized and non virtualized enviroments for creating zfs pools or any other files system where there is possiblity of change in /dev/sdX block device ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the SCSI device type being used doesn't match any of the udev rules, so the normal `by-id` symlinks aren't being created. You might want to let the Ubuntu systemd/udev maintainers know that your ESXI SCSI disk device isn't working properly.

As a workaround, you can create a **persistent name** for your device by creating a new custom udev rule file. [This guide](https://oracle-base.com/articles/linux/udev-scsi-rules-configuration-in-oracle-linux) is the easiest to read that I've found, even though it's written for Oracle Linux. I think Ubuntu 16.04 uses the newer `udevadm` instead of `udevinfo`.

So, for example, you can try `udevadm test /block/sda` to see which udev rules your device matches, and which symlinks are being created. Then you can create your own rule to match your device's serial number, and create whatever symlink you want - `/dev/disk/by-id/...`, `/dev/disk/by-uuid/...`, or even `/dev/mySCSIDevice`.